# How to add a splash screen to my android tv app ?

Tags: android, android-tv

does anyone know how to add a splash screen to an Android TV App ? what is making it hard for me is that the main activity should have Theme.Leanback in order to be accepted in the google play , and to have a splash screen you need your own style/theme. So how to do this ?

Comment: can you extend from the Theme? something like 
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Leanback">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/splash_background</item>
    </style>`

Comment: I'm facing the similar issue... How did you solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can customise Leanback's [OnboardingFragment](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tvleanback/ui/OnboardingFragment.java) slightly to display it as splash screen. `OnboardingFragment` allows you to add on-boarding steps but if you don't need them you can just set `setLogoResourceId` inside `onCreateView`.

Note that it crashes if you keep page count to zero so keep page count to one and splash duration greater than `LOGO_SPLASH_PAUSE_DURATION_MS = 1333` otherwise a page with "Get Started" button will be displayed.

The idea is to use onboarding fragment with just a splash screen initially and add on-boarding steps as your application grows.

OnboardingFragment

```
public class OnboardingFragment extends android.support.v17.leanback.app.OnboardingFragment {
    private static final long SPLASH_DURATION_MS = 2000;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        if (view != null) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        setLogoResourceId(R.drawable.logo);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                onFinishFragment();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, SPLASH_DURATION_MS);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishFragment() {
        super.onFinishFragment();
        // Our onboarding is done
        // Let's go back to the MainActivity
        getActivity().finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getPageCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getPageTitle(int pageIndex) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getPageDescription(int pageIndex) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected View onCreateBackgroundView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected View onCreateContentView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

OnboardingActivity

```
/*
 * OnboardingActivity for OnboardingFragment
 */
public class OnboardingActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.onboarding);
    }
}
```

onboarding.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/onboarding_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.android.tvleanback.ui.OnboardingFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Declare `OnboardingActivity` inside `AndroidManifest`

```
<activity android:name=".ui.OnboardingActivity"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback.Onboarding" />
```

Start `OnboardingActivity` from `MainActivity's` `onCreate`

Comment: would not just extending the theme would do ? 
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Leanback"> <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/splash_background</it‌​em> </style>

Comment: But most people use a splash screen to load extra stuff in the background (e.g., slow libraries, etc.)...I'd think your splash should be part of your MainActivity done by adding a background image to your theme like you do w/ mobile apps?

Answer (score 0):

Visit following site and copy code from there and make changes accorting to your activity name,img name.also make changes on your manifest to start app with spash screen

http://www.coderefer.com/android-splash-screen-example-tutorial/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but this is only for mobile, but I am asking for TV

Comment: Do you have any problem with applying this technique? It looks like it should be working