# How can I create better splash screen when run app in TV?

Tags: java, android

I am create one mobile application. when I also run on TV its working properly but `Splash screen` is scratched or blur because its not take image from `tvdpi` so any one help me `how can I create better splash screen when run app in TV?`

I have also big splash image for TV resolution but I don`t know where is it put so get better image.

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301584/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-my-android-tv-app

Comment: random fact: the `Nexus 7` display has `tvdpi`.

Comment: Thanks dear for your response.
i try tvdpi but its not fix all TV with tvdpi so you can use simply `drawable-land` folder. its work properly in my case

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a logo as splash screen should be, you can use layer list with the logo image Please, look at this for details.

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/